# Вывод строки из таблицы базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю вывод через `row`:

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php echo $row['loc'];  ?>
</body>
    </html>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Comment: Народ, за что минусуете? Если человек не знает - это же не смертельно, затем все тут и собрались, чтобы не стесняясь задать любой, даже самый нубский вопрос

Comment: @zippp нубский вопрос - без проблем, 82 нубских вопроса - пардон, в печь.

Comment: @sh4dow +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначало надо подключиться к БД а после этого только выбирать и вставлять туда и от туда данные.